# How to use WebView to display html pages in ebook reader fashion?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a collection of html files on my android device. I need to display them in my application in a special way: I want to split long pages to few smaller pieces, so they could fit to the device height. I am not sure is it possible to achieve this with the built-in facilities. What can I do with this problem?

Comment: When a page is too big to fit the screen, I want to have a possibility to move a content to the next page. I don't want scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should not be using a webview here.

Try the following approach :

You can use the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw each page. The canvas will give you it's height & width. Using this you can draw each line on the canvas using [Drawtext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) based on the width & height which are available.

So you would basically be calculating how many letters can fit in a line , take that many words , taking care you don't split any words and keep drawing the text. Also you could use different worker threads to work on different paragraphs to make the rendering faster.

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

or

```
String yourhtmlpage = "<html><body>You scored <b>hello world</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourhtmlpage, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: So what about the pagination in OP's question?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your answer. I think you mean 'load in different HTML for each page'. Could you make a trivial edit to this answer so I can undo my downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Short of building your own HTML parsing reader, I can't think of any other way than using CSS and JavaScript to split content up into pages.

An example of a library you could use is [Monocle](http://monocle.inventivelabs.com.au/). I haven't used it myself, but the main page says you can use it to render...

> ...XHTML files with a defined linear progression, and optionally a nested hierarchy of sections or chapters — that’s supported. In full colour.